# How to set indicators above image

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to set bullet indicators above the image?

```css
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!--Slide Show Starts-->
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">Acharya Tulsi</div>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">Acharya Mahapragya</div>
  <img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/download-happy-janmashtami-hd-images.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">Acharya Mahashraman</div>
  <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/free_high_resolution_images_for_download-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="text" style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
<!--Slide Show Ends-->
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
<div>
  <h2><center>Directory</center></h2>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type Sirname to get details" id=""><br><center><input type="submit" Value="Search" id=""></center>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I need somehow like the image

[image]

Also if I clear text box and submit button I will have the same thing I want.

Comment: This question is quite well specified, but the number of answers below inclines me to think that it is perhaps too broad for Stack Overflow. Moreover, if people are giving of their time for free, rushing respondents for an answer, or dumping "not working" on them and expecting them to fix your problems for free, is rather beyond the pale. Stack Overflow is not a resource where you can get free work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner solution is to use [bootstrap's carousel](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp).

Here is a working demo:

```css
    .carousel-caption {
  top: 0;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" alt="Slide 1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
Acharya Tulsi
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/download-happy-janmashtami-hd-images.jpg" alt="Slide 2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
Acharya Mahapragya
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/free_high_resolution_images_for_download-1.jpg" alt="image three">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
Acharya Mahashraman
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<div>
  <h2><center>Directory</center></h2>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type Sirname to get details" id="">
      <br>
      <center>
        <input type="submit" Value="Search" id="">
      </center>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @BabaluPandey Captions have been added. you should be able to play around with positioning if top center isnt where you want the captions to go. Default for bootstrap captions is bottom center.

Comment: sir it helped me out. Thank you for taking out your time for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your `slideshow-container` div and set `position: relative`.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!--Slide Show Starts-->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">Acharya Tulsi</div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">Acharya Mahapragya</div>
    <img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/download-happy-janmashtami-hd-images.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">Acharya Mahashraman</div>
    <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/free_high_resolution_images_for_download-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="text" style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
    <span class="dot"></span> 
  </div>
</div> <!-- CLOSING TAG -->

<div>
  <h2><center>Directory</center></h2>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type Sirname to get details" id=""><br><center><input type="submit" Value="Search" id=""></center>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you have to set your `slideshow-container` as `relative`.

Comment: It didn't help me out. Have same problem as with absolute.

Comment: I've updated my answer with `position: relative;`. This works. But maybe you mean the jumping effect. This happens, because your images have different heights.

Comment: Thank you for taking time for me. But I was more helpful by @Ethilium sir's answer.

Answer (score 0):

change the `.text` css like this .increase the bottom pixel

```
.text{
  bottom: 120px;
}
```

```css
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!--Slide Show Starts-->
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">Acharya Tulsi</div>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">Acharya Mahapragya</div>
  <img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/download-happy-janmashtami-hd-images.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">Acharya Mahashraman</div>
  <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/free_high_resolution_images_for_download-1.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div class="text" style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
<!--Slide Show Ends-->
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
<div>
  <h2><center>Directory</center></h2>
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type Sirname to get details" id=""><br><center><input type="submit" Value="Search" id=""></center>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It helped, but if I would add more texts and div, I will have to change it accordingly...It will be better if it fixes with auto...

Comment: Thanks for taking time for me...but I got the perfect answer from @Ethilium sir.